# Copy a Saved CSV Import from Sandbox to Production?

Tags: csv, import, sandbox, netsuite

Is there a way to copy/move a Saved CSV Import configured in the Sandbox over to our Production system?

Thanks,

Jay

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can include CSV Imports when you create a SuiteBundle.